# Initializing Jenkins 2.0 with pipeline in init.groovy.d script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-job-dsl

For automation, I would like to initialize a Jenkins 2.0 instance with a pipeline job. I want to create a Groovy script that is copied to the `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/` folder on startup. The script should create a Jenkins 2.0 Pipeline job for processing a Jenkinsfile from SCM.

I cannot find the relevant Javadoc for the 2.0 pipeline classes or examples of how to do this.

Previously, using Job DSL to create a pipeline, I used a Groovy script to create a `FreeStyleProject` with an `ExecuteDslScripts` builder. That job would then be the Job DSL seed job.

One option is to use an init script to create a Job DSL seed job to create a Jenkins 2.0 pipeline. It just seems unnecessarily complex.

I am experimenting in this repo: https://github.com/martinmosegaard/vigilant-sniffle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to create one simple pipeline job, you can use the Jenkins API. But that really only works well when creating one simple job, for a complex setup you need some abstraction like Job DSL.

Start here: http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#createProject(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String).

Example:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob

WorkflowJob job = Jenkins.instance.createProject(WorkflowJob, 'my-pipeline')
```

Then you need to populate the job, e.g. setting a flow definition.

Or you can wait for the [System Config DSL Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/system-config-dsl-plugin) to be ready. But it has not been released yet and I'm not sure if it can create jobs.

Comment: Probably want to add: `job.definition = new CpsFlowDefinition('…', true)`

Comment: Thanks. I might stick with Job DSL and then `workflowJob`. My problem is that from `javadoc.jenkins-ci.org`, it is hard to find what I need. For example, who implements `Job/JobT`, example use cases, etc. I found `WorkflowJob` on GitHub by googling - https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job - but there really are a lot of plugins to search if you don't know what you are looking for exactly.

Answer (score 13):

With Job DSL 1.47 ([merged May 10, 2016](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/pull/837), [released](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/releases/)) you can use the Job DSL API directly from the init script without the need to create a seed job.

```
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptLoader
import javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.JenkinsJobManagement

def jobDslScript = new File('jobs.groovy')
def workspace = new File('.')

def jobManagement = new JenkinsJobManagement(System.out, [:], workspace)

new DslScriptLoader(jobManagement).runScript(jobDslScript.text)
```

See [PR #837](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/pull/837) for details.

Comment: Thanks, that will also be really helpful.

Comment: Thank you. This piece of code worked and is really helpful. However, a link to some documentation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: how can you add parameters to the groovy script?